# Refresh Tableau Live dashboard automatically at Tableau Server in every 5 seconds

Tags: python, tableau-api

I want to refresh Tableau Live dashboard on Server automatically in every 5 seconds. Is it possible without using Extension or JS?

Answer (score 0):

Extensions and JS are the only methods I know of to do this natively with Tableau. You will probably have to look to a 3rd party add on for your browser. Here is one for chrome.

[Chrome Auto-Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh/ifooldnmmcmlbdennkpdnlnbgbmfalko)

Comment: The requirement is to whosoever is logging to the Server at that time for that particular dashboard, the auto refresh will work for all logged in user. Do you suggest any other method? Currently, I'm using Tableau 2018.2

Comment: What is the reason for excluding extensions? This would be the preferred method and not too hard to setup even with limited js knowledge.